# MySQL delete duplicated rows keep none

Tags: mysql, duplicates

My table looks like this:

| Event_id | Species |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Dog |
| 1 | Horse |
| 2 | Dog |
| 3 | Cat |
| 4 | Fish |
| 4 | Bird |
| 5 | Cat |

I dont want to keep any of the rows which have a duplicated event_id, as I cant be sure about the species type of the event. How do I remove both rows of the table in mysql? I dont have a unique id for each row.

The output should look like this:

| Event_id | Species |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Dog |
| 3 | Cat |
| 5 | Cat |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicated, but on Database Administrators See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69592

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution I tested on MySQL 8.0 (required for the use of `with`):

```
mysql> create table mytable (event_id int, species varchar(20));
mysql> insert into mytable (Event_id,Species) values (1,'Dog'), (1,'Horse'), 
    (2,'Dog'), (3,'Cat'), (4,'Fish'), (4,'Bird'), (5,'Cat');

mysql> with cte as (select event_id from mytable group by event_id having count(*)>1) 
    delete mytable from mytable join cte using (event_id);

mysql> select * from mytable;
+----------+---------+
| event_id | species |
+----------+---------+
|        2 | Dog     |
|        3 | Cat     |
|        5 | Cat     |
+----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach would be:

```
delete t1 
from my_tbl as t1  
inner join  (  select event_id
               from my_tbl
               group by event_id
               having count(*) >1 
              )as t2 
on t1.event_id=t2.event_id;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/155

Or with sybquery:

```
delete from my_tbl  
where event_id not in ( select t1.event_id from (select event_id
                                              from my_tbl
                                              group by event_id
                                              having count(*) =1) as t1
                      ) ;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/151

Below query return the event_id that exist only once. So you can delete with the condition `event_id not in`.

```
select event_id
from my_tbl
group by event_id
having count(*) =1
```